# Posicionar scroll en la pagina y no en el Dialog Angular-Material

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

Como puedo hacer para que el `scroll` del `dialog` sea de la pagina y no del `dialog`, creo que se puede hacer con `css`, pero lo he intentando no logro una solución.

```html
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <link rel = "stylesheet"
         href = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
      <script language = "javascript">
         angular
            .module('firstApplication', ['ngMaterial'])
            .controller('dialogController', dialogController);

         function dialogController ($scope, $mdDialog) {
            $scope.status = '';
            $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5];
            $scope.showAlert = function(ev) {
               $mdDialog.show (
                  $mdDialog.alert()
                     .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#dialogContainer')))
                     .clickOutsideToClose(true)
                     .title('TutorialsPoint.com')
                     .textContent('This is example This is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is example This is example This is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is example This is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is example This is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is example This is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is example This is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is exampleThis is example')
                     .ariaLabel('Welcome to TutorialsPoint.com')
                     .ok('Ok!')
                     .targetEvent(ev)
               );
            };
            
         }                 
      </script>      
   </head>
   
   <body ng-app = "firstApplication"> 
      <div id = "dialogContainer" ng-controller = "dialogController as ctrl"
         layout = "row" ng-cloak>
         <md-content>
            <h4>Standard Alert</h4>
            <md-button class = "md-primary md-raised"
               ng-click = "showAlert($event)" flex = "100"  flex-gt-md = "auto">
               Alert
            </md-button>
            
            
         </md-content>   
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No estoy seguro de que es lo que intentas conseguir, podrias explicarte mejor?